# How to stop seeing DEBUG output in output log Intellij IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

I am using third party code that uses:

```
if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
    logger.debug("Message");
}
```

I'm getting these messages in my output even though I'm using the standard run configuration, and it's only happening on my instance of this particular project so I'm not sure what I'm missing.

I've tried deleting the run configuration and starting it again but I keep getting it in my output.

How do I stop this?

[SOLVED]

Comment: What do you mean by "my output"? Note that the IDEA toolwindow that shows the output usually has a dropdown where you can select which log levels you want to show.#

Comment: I mean the output console, where you would expect to see `Hello` from
``System.out.println("Hello");``

Comment: @biroshima Make sure the logger configuration is loaded properly via classpath, property or a file depending how it's supposed to be initialized.

Answer (score 3):

I found this in another project, copied it across and it's behaving as I would expect now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

This was in `logback.xml` in `src>main>resources`

Thanks to those that commented!